# Issue while displaying Dialog on Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

The following code displays date picker(as a popup dialog) when the user clicks on an EditText . showDialog() calls onCreateDialog(). The code works fine except when it is implemented in a Fragment. In Fragment , the dialog is not getting displayed.

```
edtTxtDateTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // Displaying Date & Time as a dialog

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have tried to implement the same behaviour using DialogFragment  API , but am unable to get the dialog when EditText is clicked.

Any suggestions / hints will be helpful.

Comment: When you call it in the fragment are you calling getActivity().showDialog()?

Comment: Many things can be wrong here... show the actual code...

Comment: have you followed the example in the reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct context to display the dialog within your Fragment code.   You need to be using the parent Activity's context.  Within your Fragment, you can get the Activity (and correct context) by calling:

```
getActivity();
```